# Array items only appearing once when filtering in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

In this React code what I'm trying to do is getting all items from the list that match with what type in the text input that's in the setManName function (also there is one in setModeName function). It works, but when I delete the text input and start over, the items disappear and will not appear anymore, not showing on the screen unless I reload the page again and start over again. I am using inludes() method, which works fine, but once I delete a letter or whole word and start over again it doesn't work. What's the problem here? Should I be using a different approach? Like another useEffect or something?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {

  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const [openFilterCt, setOpenFilterCt] = useState(false)

  const [term1, setTerm1] = useState()
  const [term2, setTerm2] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://private-anon-af560a53c6-carsapi1.apiary-mock.com/cars")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setItems(data)
      })
  }, [])

  function setManName(e) {
    setTerm1(e.target.value);
    let u = items.filter(item => {
      **return item.make.includes(e.target.value)**
    })
    setItems(u)
  }

  function setModName(e) {
    setTerm2(e.target.value);
    let u = items.filter(item => {
      **return item.model.includes(e.target.value)**
    })
    setItems(u)
  }

  function hi() {
    setOpenFilterCt(!openFilterCt)
  }  

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React Search &amp; Filter</h1>
      <div>
        <h3 onClick={hi}>Filter</h3>
        <div className={openFilterCt ? "show" : "hide"}>
          <label>
            Name of manufacturer: <input type="text" value={term1} onChange={setManName} />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            Name of model: <input type="text" value={term2} onChange={setModName} />
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      {items.slice(0, 50).map((a, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} style={{border: "1px solid black", margin: "10px", padding: "5px"}}>
            <p>Manufacturer: {a.make[0].toUpperCase() + a.make.slice(1)}</p>
            <p>Model: {a.model}</p>
            
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the items object, so any items not in a search will not show up even after deleting characters. This solution will dynamically filter the items, rather than removing them from the array.

Additionally, you should provide a default value to the `term1` and `term2` states. Without a default value, the inputs are switching from uncontrolled to controlled inputs, a practice that is discouraged in React.

See [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-mendel-hbgb8?file=/src/App.js:0-1807).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [openFilterCt, setOpenFilterCt] = useState(false);

  const [term1, setTerm1] = useState("");
  const [term2, setTerm2] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://private-anon-af560a53c6-carsapi1.apiary-mock.com/cars")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setItems(data);
      });
  }, []);

  function setManName(e) {
    setTerm1(e.target.value);
  }

  function setModName(e) {
    setTerm2(e.target.value);
  }

  function filterItems(item) {
    if (term1 && !item.make.includes(term1)) return false;
    if (term2 && !item.model.includes(term2)) return false;

    return true;
  }

  function hi() {
    setOpenFilterCt(!openFilterCt);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React Search &amp; Filter</h1>
      <div>
        <h3 onClick={hi}>Filter</h3>
        <div className={openFilterCt ? "show" : "hide"}>
          <label>
            Name of manufacturer:{" "}
            <input type="text" value={term1} onInput={setManName} />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            Name of model:{" "}
            <input type="text" value={term2} onInput={setModName} />
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      {items
        .filter(filterItems)
        .slice(0, 50)
        .map((a, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              style={{
                border: "1px solid black",
                margin: "10px",
                padding: "5px"
              }}
            >
              <p>Manufacturer: {a.make[0].toUpperCase() + a.make.slice(1)}</p>
              <p>Model: {a.model}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: So in this code .filter() method will always be invoked based on its return value of true, if both conditions are false?

Comment: These return values, do they indicate that the filter method will / won't be executed?

Comment: The filter method will filter items from the array based on the return value. If true is returned, the item will be included in the new array. If it is false, it will not.

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed it for your ***model search***, you can do the same for the manufacturer search. There may be more optimal ways, but this is something I worked it out.

What you need to do is preserve your original list. `.filter()` actually changes the original list, and when the response is blank, the original data is gone. So I just preserved the old data

```
const [orItem, setOrItems] = useState([]);

const prevList = orItem;

  function setModName(e) {
    setTerm2(e.target.value);
    let u = prevList.filter((item) => {
      return item.model.includes(e.target.value);
    });
    setItems(u);
  }
```

You can see you code in action here for model search:

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-mcclintock-46ncr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: As this answer does not fully solve the issue, I assumed you had downvoted the other answers, especially as they were downvoted as soon as they were posted. If you didn't, I'm sorry, although my view of this answer still stands.

Comment: Hey, wont filter just create the new array based on the values of the old array? Instead of changing the original array?

Comment: @David - just because we have used state after the filer, `setItems(u)` it will override the value

Comment: @Tushar, thanks for pointing that out, I didn't write the filter method properly :) Needs some fine-tuning.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not modify the original array `items`. You need to create another one(another state variable) `filteredItems` so you can reset to the original state, also I believe there is another error here `item.model.includes(e.target.value)`, it will always return `false` if the text is empty.

```
function setManName(e) {
    setTerm1(e.target.value);
    if(e.target.value){
      let u = items.filter(item => {
       return item.make.includes(e.target.value)
      })
      setFilteredItems(u)
    }else{
     setItems(items)
    }
  }
```

Also `useEffect` hook should be something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://private-anon-af560a53c6-carsapi1.apiary-mock.com/cars")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setItems(data)
        setFilteredItems(data)
      })
  }, [])
```

And make sure to `map` over `filteredItems`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are resetting the value that you receive from the given URL. You should be maintaining a separate list for visibility you could go by approach 1. given below. Its the best I could do without modifying lots of your code however this is typically an over/mis use of states. Remember React is called react because of its amazing capability to react when the state changes.
The Approach2 realizes just that, you can be smart with the filter and alter it as you need. your search to behave.

```
// Approach 1

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import "./style.css";

export default function App() {

  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [visibleItems, setVisibleItems] = useState([]);
  const [openFilterCt, setOpenFilterCt] = useState(false)

  const [term1, setTerm1] = useState()
  const [term2, setTerm2] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://private-anon-af560a53c6-carsapi1.apiary-mock.com/cars")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setItems(data);
        setVisibleItems(data);
      })
  }, [])

  function setManName(e) {
    // setTerm1(e.target.value);
    let u = items.filter(item => {
      if(e.target.value){
        return item.make.includes(e.target.value)
      }
      return true;      
    })
    setVisibleItems(u)
  }

  function setModName(e) {
    // setTerm2(e.target.value);
    let u = items.filter(item => {
      return item.model.includes(e.target.value)
    })
    setVisibleItems(u)
  }

  function hi() {
    setOpenFilterCt(!openFilterCt)
  }  

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React Search &amp; Filter</h1>
      <div>
        <h3 onClick={hi}>Filter</h3>
        <div className={openFilterCt ? "show" : "hide"}>
          <label>
            Name of manufacturer: <input type="text" value={term1} onChange={setManName} />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            Name of model: <input type="text" value={term2} onChange={setModName} />
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      {visibleItems.slice(0, 50).map((a, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} style={{border: "1px solid black", margin: "10px", padding: "5px"}}>
            <p>Manufacturer: {a.make[0].toUpperCase() + a.make.slice(1)}</p>
            <p>Model: {a.model}</p>
            
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// Approach2
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [openFilterCt, setOpenFilterCt] = useState(false);

  const [term1, setTerm1] = useState("");
  const [term2, setTerm2] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://private-anon-af560a53c6-carsapi1.apiary-mock.com/cars")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setItems(data);
      });
  }, []);

  function setManName(e) {
    setTerm1(e.target.value);
  }

  function setModName(e) {
    setTerm2(e.target.value);
  }

  function hi() {
    setOpenFilterCt(!openFilterCt);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React Search &amp; Filter</h1>
      <div>
        <h3 onClick={hi}>Filter</h3>
        <div className={openFilterCt ? "show" : "hide"}>
          <label>
            Name of manufacturer:{" "}
            <input type="text" value={term1} onChange={setManName} />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            Name of model:{" "}
            <input type="text" value={term2} onChange={setModName} />
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      {items
        .filter((item) => {
          return item.make.includes(term1) && item.model.includes(term2);
        })
        .slice(0, 50)
        .map((a, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              style={{
                border: "1px solid black",
                margin: "10px",
                padding: "5px"
              }}
            >
              <p>Manufacturer: {a.make[0].toUpperCase() + a.make.slice(1)}</p>
              <p>Model: {a.model}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow. The second approach looks really nice. However, I don't understand the filter() method though. Its return value will run only if both conditions are true (since you use && here), right? But if I use only one search list will still be filtered, why is that? Shouldn't we use || here?

Comment: @David Yeah sure you can play around with the conditions of the filter function to get the desired result, the possibilities are endless. I just wanted to demonstrate how something similar can be achieved in a more "reactive" way. If you end up with performance issues because of large data, I'd recommend using Throttling or Debouncing to reduce the number of times the items are filtered upon https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf